# How to initialize shared pointers in constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constructor, initialization, make-shared

I am trying to initialize objects from other classes in my constructor as shared pointers. I need a shred pointer because I need a reference to use in another method in ...

header

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass() ;
   ~MyClass() {};
   void myMethod();
private:
   std::shared_ptr<dds::pub::Publisher>m_pub;
   std::shared_ptr<dds::domain::DomainParticipant>m_part;
};
```

cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass()  
{
  m_part = std::make_shared<dds::domain::DomainParticipant>(domain::default_id());
  m_pub = std::make_shared<dds::pub::Publisher>(m_part);
}
MyClass::myMethod()
{
  //m_part, m_pub are used here 
}
```

what am I missing here?

```
Error   C2039   'delegate': is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<dds::domain::DomainParticipant>'
```

**dds::pub::Publisher**

```
namespace dds
{
  namespace pub
  {
     typedef dds::pub::detail::Publisher Publisher;
  }
}
```

**Publisher**

```
namespace dds { namespace pub { namespace detail {
typedef 
dds::pub::TPublisher<org::eclipse::cyclonedds::pub::PublisherDelegate> Publisher;
} } }
```

**PublisherDelegate**

```
namespace dds { namespace pub { namespace detail {
    typedef 
dds::pub::TPublisher<org::eclipse::cyclonedds::pub::PublisherDelegate> Publisher;
} } }


class OMG_DDS_API PublisherDelegate : public 
org::eclipse::cyclonedds::core::EntityDelegate
{
public:
typedef ::dds::core::smart_ptr_traits< PublisherDelegate >::ref_type ref_type;
typedef ::dds::core::smart_ptr_traits< PublisherDelegate >::weak_ref_type weak_ref_type;

PublisherDelegate(const dds::domain::DomainParticipant& dp,
                  const dds::pub::qos::PublisherQos& qos,
                  dds::pub::PublisherListener* listener,
                  const dds::core::status::StatusMask& event_mask);
```

**TPublisher**

```
template <typename DELEGATE>
class dds::pub::TPublisher : public dds::core::TEntity<DELEGATE>
{
public:

   typedef dds::pub::PublisherListener                 Listener;

public:
   OMG_DDS_REF_TYPE_PROTECTED_DC(TPublisher, dds::core::TEntity, DELEGATE)
   OMG_DDS_IMPLICIT_REF_BASE(TPublisher)

   TPublisher(const dds::domain::DomainParticipant& dp);

   TPublisher(const dds::domain::DomainParticipant& dp,
           const dds::pub::qos::PublisherQos& qos,
           dds::pub::PublisherListener* listener = NULL,
           const dds::core::status::StatusMask& mask = dds::core::status::StatusMask::none());
```

I tried the method given in answer got new error,

```
Error   C2672   'std::dynamic_pointer_cast': no matching overloaded function  in TPublisher.hpp
```

Comment: `TPublisher` does not have a constructor that takes a `shared_ptr`, so I would expect there to be more than one error. (Your motivation for using `shared_ptr` is odd, and seems cut off.) Also, look at the complete error messages in the output window instead of using the error list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `m_pub` should be initialised like this

```
m_pub = std::make_shared<dds::pub::Publisher>(*m_part);
```

The class `dds::pub::Publisher` a.k.a. `dds::pub::TPublisher` has the constructor taking `const dds::domain::DomainParticipant` by reference.

The answer is changed after the question has been updated.

Comment: I added some code snippets for your reference.... its code base of cyclonedds

Comment: Still no Publisher constructor (now this is TPublisher). In any case I think my fix is correct. Try it.

Comment: I tried the method given in answer got a new error,

Error   C2672   'std::dynamic_pointer_cast': no matching overloaded function in TPublisher.hpp

Comment: Not enough context to help you. Please try to make a [mcve], it is difficult in your case, but while making it you might find the solution.